# Change user id and group id ownership of files within a tarball?

Tags: users, tar

I have a tarball and the files it contains do not have the right user and group ownership. Files are owned `jenkins:jenkins` and I'd like them to be owned `naftuli:othergroup`.

Is there a way for me to edit the tarball in place so that the files it contains become owned by `naftuli:othergroup`?

The problem I'm facing is that at the time of the tarball creation, the `jenkins` user doesn't have permissions to `chown` things to different users and groups. At the time of extraction, I will have permissions to create those files as the users mentioned, so I need to edit the user ids and group ids within the tarball.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot change permissions explicitly on extraction, but you can put the preferred identities into the tarball on creation (even when not running as `root`).

```
tar cvf /tmp/tarball.tar --owner=naftuli --group othergroup files...
```

If the source system doesn't know your account details you can suffix the names with the preferred uid and gid (e.g. `--owner=naftuli:3000`).

Alternatively, if you already have a tarball you can extract the files created by jenkins as yourself (`naftuli:othergroup`) and because you are not `root` the files will become owned by you.

Comment: Is there a way to actually _edit_ the tarball? This is a good solution.

Comment: @NaftuliTzviKay I don't know any way of editing the tarball in place. The Perl solution offered to you can read and write the tarball as a stream. But like I say, if you extract the tarball and you're not root then the files will be owned by you (rather than by the original writer) anyway.

Comment: Note: `--user` seems to be Linux-only

Comment: Can't find the `--user` option in GNU `tar` 1.34, but there is `--owner=NAME[:UID]`.

Comment: @StefanvandenAkker thank you for picking that up. I wonder how I got `--user`? I'll amend the answer now

Answer (score 6):

[Archive::Tar](https://metacpan.org/pod/Archive::Tar) or similar software would be one method.

```
% touch foo  
% tar cvf x foo
foo
% tar tvf x          
-rw-rw-r--  1 jdoe12   jdoe12           0 May  6 20:36 foo
% perl -MArchive::Tar -e '$t=Archive::Tar->new;$t->read("x");$t->chown("foo","root");$t->write("y")'
% tar tvf y
-rw-rw-r--  1 root     jdoe12           0 May  6 20:36 foo
%
```

Answer (score 2):

Note the answer using `Archive::Tar` reads the archive into memory. Using Python's `tarfile` module, it is possible to avoid this. Unfortunately, I haven't managed to stream from `stdin` yet, as `extractfile` tries to seek.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import tarfile
import sys

with tarfile.open(name=sys.argv[1], mode="r") as in_tar, \
    tarfile.open(fileobj=sys.stdout.buffer, mode="w|") as out_tar:
    for member in in_tar.getmembers():
        member.uname = member.gname = "root"
        if member.isfile():
            with in_tar.extractfile(member) as file:
                out_tar.addfile(member, file)
        else:
            out_tar.addfile(member)
```

**Update**: The following Go program does work on streams:

```
package main

import (
        "archive/tar"
        "io"
        "log"
        "os"
)

func main() {
        tr := tar.NewReader(os.Stdin)
        tw := tar.NewWriter(os.Stdout)

        for {
                hdr, err := tr.Next()
                if err == io.EOF {
                        break
                } else if err != nil {
                        log.Fatal(err)
                }

                hdr.Uname, hdr.Gname = "root", "root"
                if err := tw.WriteHeader(hdr); err != nil {
                        log.Fatal(err)
                }

                if hdr.Typeflag == tar.TypeReg {
                        if _, err := io.Copy(tw, tr); err != nil {
                                log.Fatal(err)
                        }
                }
        }

        if err := tw.Close(); err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
}
```

Comment: The problem in your code is that you use `getmembers()`. That function first reads the whole archive before returning the list of members. This means that to read a file in the archive, `extractfile` would have to read backwards. The solution is, to iterate through the members one-by-one without reading in the whole archive at once. You do this by using `for member in in_tar` instead. Then you can open `in_tar` with `mode="r|*"` and things will work as expected.

Comment: The implementation in go is still superior because in contrast to Python's `tarfile` module, `archive/tar` from go supports extended attributes in the PAX header.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using macOS, its version of tar has an "mtree" extension that can do this.  The resulting tar file can be extracted in Linux (i.e., it's portable).

From the EXAMPLES section of the macOS tar manpage:

```
$ cat input.mtree
#mtree
usr/bin uid=0 gid=0 mode=0755 type=dir
usr/bin/ls uid=0 gid=0 mode=0755 type=file content=myls
$ tar -cvf output.tar @input.mtree
```

The `#mtree` comment at the top of the input file is required.  There are also `uname` and `gname` options (instead of `uid`/`gid`) for setting symbolic names instead of numeric values.  See `man mtree 5` for a list of all keywords.